# How to close or recover a hanging connection to amazon-ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, session-manager

I was using `aws cli` to connect to an EC2 instance. I had network issues and the connection broke.
I was left with a hanging connection, both on my side (the cli wouldn't take any keystroke) and on the EC2 (a bash process kept running).

So I had to wait until the connection timeout (several minutes).

When this happen with ssh, I can simply disconnect using escape characters `~.      Disconnect.`.

What would be the approach in EC2 commenction?

Comment: Why not connect to the box over ssh ?

Comment: That's not enabled.

Comment: A more meaningful response might start "ssh is not enabled because..."  AFAIK having ssh on a Linux EC2 instance is a standard practice (appropriately secured and firewalled), with the console there for emergency access.

Comment: ssh is not enabled because of company policies
It's not something I can change.